# Fencing yard and then cementing Area - What to do first?

Tags: installation, fence, patio

I live in Midwest in a townhouse. Having problems with new neighbors dogs crapping in yard.  Planning to surround yard with 5ft chainlink fence and also cementing the encased area to use as patio with in-ground drain. There won't be any soil area left.  In which order should these two tasks be done?  Which contractors do i need, masonry or fencing company or both? The downspout is in the ground.  Is there a way to tie a drainage system from cement pad into downspout? Area measures about 5x7ft.

Answer (score 1):

There are local landscaping companies that would do all of this around me.  I would call a couple.   Also with a small area some pavers might look a lot nicer than a concrete slab and might save you a lot of money.

But before you start anything you need to make sure that your townhouse board is OK with any of this.  There might be a specific type of fence that you need to get and bylaws on doing cement work and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you get a general contractor, you'll need both a concrete company and a fencing company.  If I were doing this, I'd prep the footings for the fence first, then lay the concrete, and finish with the fencing.  Using a bull float to finish the concrete would be extremely difficult in a 5x7 fenced in area. This is likely going to require some degree of coordination between the two companies, so it might not be a bad idea to just let a general contractor deal with that aspect of it if you aren't comfortable doing it yourself.